# Showing a function is not Hölder continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, holder-spaces

I am trying to find a function continuous on $[0, 1]$ which is nowhere Hölder continuous for $0 \leq \alpha < 1$. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) we have the example:

\begin{equation}
f = \left\{ \begin{array}{rcl} 0 & \mbox{for}& x = 0 \\ \frac{1}{\ln(x)} & \mbox{for} & x > 0\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

According to Wikipedia, this function is not Hölder continuous for any $\alpha$, on the interval $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$, so my assumption was to simply use the same function, but with the non-zero map given by $f(x) = \frac{1}{\ln(\frac{x}{2})}$. However, on closer inspection the original function does not agree with the condition I am using to check if a function is not Hölder continuous, so I am wondering what part of my reasoning is incorrect.

To check if a function is not Hölder continuous, I am attempting to check if the following limit holds as $x \rightarrow 0$.

\begin{equation}
\frac{|f(t+x) - f(t)|}{|x|^\alpha} \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}

With $t \in [0, 1]$, but my attempts to evaluate the limit at various points have given me a limit of $0$. Under this condition, is the function in the Wikipedia article still not Hölder continuous, and is my attempt to fit the function to the interval $[0,1]$ valid? If anyone can clarify where I'm getting lost I would appreciate it

Comment: The function Wikipedia gives is only not Holder at $x= 0$. At other places its even $C^∞$.

Comment: From the article, "It does not satisfy a Hölder condition of any order, however." If it's only not Hölder at $0$, what is the purpose of defining it in that way?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking - defining it in what way, exactly?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion - I just meant that if their example was only not Hölder at $0$, it might as well have been defined as $0$ for all $x$ instead of the separate definition for $x > 0$. Edit: Also, ignore the first sentence in my comment above, rereading the article I realise I misunderstood their example.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you understand. The function that is 0 for all $x$ is a smooth function and hence in particular, $C^\alpha$ for every $\alpha$. Wikipedia's function is not $\alpha$-Holder at $x=0$ for any $\alpha ∈ (0,1)$. A function is said to be $\alpha$-Holder if it is $\alpha$-Holder at every point; hence this function is not $\alpha$-Holder. However, it is not nowhere $\alpha$-Holder.

Comment: I think I see now where my understanding of the example was off, thank you for clarifying. In that case, are there any examples of functions which are nowhere $\alpha$-Hölder?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know of any, if I had to guess I would try a silly construction like $\sum_{n} \frac{|x-r_n|^{1/n}}{2^n}$ where $r_n$ is some enumeration of the rationals on [0,1].